# Custom format for Text.DateStyle.timer?

Tags: swift, swiftui, widgetkit

Say I have a Text.DateStyle.timer in WidgetKit and I want to set it so that it displays hours:minutes only, instead of hours:minutes:seconds. How can I go about this?

Comment: I have the same question. Did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score -3):

In iOS 15.0+ you can use the [formatted function](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/date/3766588-formatted):

```
Date().formatted(date: .omitted, time: .shortened)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, however I don't believe this solution is compatible with Date.timer (not to be confused with Date.time).